# device Orientation to statusBar Orientation changes

Tags: iphone, ios, uideviceorientation, nsstatusbar

I have created a device orientation listener to catch when the device is rotated, like so

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(jumpBarButtonPosition)
                                                 name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

however inside the jumpBarButtonPosition method I have changed from using UIDeviceOrientation to statusBarOrientation, so I am woundering what I could replace **UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification** with in order to only receive notifications about the statudBarOrientation changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't type it as a string:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" use:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(jumpBarButtonPosition)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: okay right.. but this dosn't look like its checking statusbarorientation, the only reason I ask this is because I would like to ignore faceUp and faceDown notifications..

Comment: The device changes the status bar's orientation. However, if you have another method that changes the orientation without the device changing, post a notification within that method.

Comment: okay thats all good.. I was just hoping to ignore those faceup facedown notifications as they are redundant for what I am worried about, thanks for the help I will mark yours as correct if i dont get any more answers in the next few hours.  cheers.